# How to make logical OR with AND,and NOT?

Tags: boolean-logic

How to create a logical OR with logical AND, and logical NOT?

Comment: this is your homework?

Comment: Yes, it is necessary to synthesize the control passage of solid logic,
logical base for using: AND, NOT

Comment: @Matten, this probably is, but I guess it is good that such questions remain. Although I knew de Morgan's law, I couldn't recall it, which brought me here. There may be others like that as well

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Check [De Morgans's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Substitution_form). You are looking for the **Substitution form**.

```
P OR Q = NOT( (NOT P) AND (NOT Q) )
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning De Morgan's law. I couldn't think of the name when answering the question myself.

Comment: But then how can I make a XOR gate using only AND and NOT?

Answer (score 17):

It's [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
A OR B = NOT ( NOT A AND NOT B )
```

Truth table for A OR B:

```
A B  X
0 0  0
0 1  1
1 0  1
1 1  1
```

Truth table for the De Morgan equivalent:

```
A B  !A  !B  (!A AND !B)   !(!A AND !B)
0 0   1   1       1              0
0 1   1   0       0              1
1 0   0   1       0              1
1 1   0   0       0              1
```

Answer (score 9):

Like `not (not x and not y)` ?

Answer (score 5):

Pretty simple:

```
A || B = !(!A && !B)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using DeMorgans law. The Negation of (Not A "And" Not B)