# Are || and ! operators sufficient to make every possible logical expression?

Tags: logic, logical-operators

The logical expression `( a && b )` *(both `a` and `b` have boolean values)* can be written like `!(!a || !b)`, for example. Doesn't this mean that `&&` is "unneccesary"? Does this mean that *all* logical expressions can be made only using `||` and `!`?

Comment: This is more of a basic symbolic logic question than a Java issue, but yes.  OR and NOT in combination can be used to construct everything else.  The same with AND and NOT. For instance, when I was in school we were taught to build everything using only NAND gates because they took fewer transistors.

Comment: Don't confuse the capability to write a statement this way with the desirability to do so.  Syntactic sugar is a **good** thing.

Comment: See also "How to make logical OR with AND,and NOT?" at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374895/how-to-make-logical-or-with-and-and-not

Comment: XOR is the same as ^

Comment: Many logic gate chips only provide NAND or NOR gates as it's possible to implement all operations with them and it makes them cheap to produce - `A and B == !A nor !B == !(!A or !B)`. Likewise `A or B == !A nand !B == !(!A and !B)`. Obviously passing the same value to both inputs of a NAND or NOR will give the same result as a simple NOT. XOR and XNOR are also possible but more complex. See De Morgan's theorem

Comment: Yes, using ! and || operators is even more options than NOR - the fact that NOR gates are sufficient means you can build all logic exclusively with expressions of the form !(A || B).

Comment: you can build a working computer and RAM just using NAND. that also means you can build stackoverflow site with only NAND gate :)

Comment: Isn't this a computer science question? I see no code here. In particular, whether this is true in practice will vary by implementation, e.g. in C++ with operating overloading it's _not_ in general.

Comment: In fact, you only need _one_ logical expression to express all logical operators: The Sheffer stroke, or "not both": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke

Comment: People seeing this question might like this [TED talk](https://www.ted.com/talks/shimon_schocken_the_self_organizing_computer_course?language=en). It's about building a computer using only NAND gates.

Comment: Please don't go writing code using nothing but `||` and `!` - it will be very unreadable and future devs may not easily grasp the code intention. Not to mention the compiler and/or hardware will ultimately do what it believes is best, ie. hardware modules will already only have NAND gates and all your code will be thrown through it, so no need to try to use only NAND (or NOR) in your code.

Comment: @SnakeDoc I don't think anyone here is advocating to do such a thing. I believe this question was more of theoretical logic question, than a programming one, really.

Comment: Also relevant [One Instruction Set Ccomputer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_instruction_set_computer). In the usual implementation the instruction is "subtract branch if negativel", but it isn't abbreviated `sbn` because there is no need to write it. Assembly code consists of ordered triples.

Comment: You can create all logical expressions using "or" || and "not" ! operators, but it doesn't mean that you should. Introducing "not" operator usually makes code more complicated to read, can be source of mistakes and misunderstandings. You should avoid "not" operator when you can. You can even replace || with + (addition) and && with * (multiplication), so you can skip more logical operators! Addition and multiplication are identical with "or" and "and" for primitive boolean data types. You can do all of that stuff, but do you really want to make your code less readable and harder to maintain?

Comment: @piotr.wittchen Do you have any links or references to best practices stating that you should avoid the not operator? I think it's completely circumstantial when the not operator makes code more or less readable. While I agree that you should generally have the minimum operators while making the code still readable, I don't agree that you should generally avoid any specific operator. And to my knowledge, you cannot replace || with addition or && with star.

Comment: @jason9187 You're right. I don't have any reference to practice of avoiding operator, but in my opinion, if you can use less amount of operators, you should do it, as you said. Generally, you shouldn't replace || with addition and && with star, but when you have two boolean values you can do that in conditional statement and it will work. Maybe it won't work in every language, but in C++ it works.

Answer (score 429, accepted):

Yes, as the other answers pointed out, the set of operators comprising of `||` and `!` is [functionally complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness). Here's a constructive proof of that, showing how to use them to express all sixteen possible logical connectives between the boolean variables `A` and `B`:

- [True](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)): `A || !A`
- [A NAND B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke): `!A || !B`
- [B implies A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_implication): `!B || A`
- [A implies B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional): `!A || B`
- [A OR B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction): `A || B`
- [Not B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation): `!B`
- [Not A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation): `!A`
- [A XOR B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or): `!(!A || B) || !(A || !B)`
- [A XNOR B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_biconditional): `!(!A || !B) || !(A || B)`
- [A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_(logic)): `A`
- [B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_(logic)): `B`
- [A NOR B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_NOR): `!(A || B)`
- [A does not imply B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_nonimplication): `!(!A || B)`
- [B does not imply A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_nonimplication): `!(!B || A)`
- [A AND B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction): `!(!A || !B)`
- [False](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_(logic)): `!(A || !A)`

Note that both NAND and NOR are by themselves functionally complete (which can be proved using the same method above), so if you want to verify that a set of operators is functionally complete, it's enough to show that you can express either NAND or NOR with it.

Here's a graph showing the [Venn diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram) for each of the connectives listed above:

[image]

[[source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Logical_connectives_Hasse_diagram.svg)]

Comment: It's hard to tell whether the question intends this, but this answer doesn't address short-circuit behaviour (relevant, since the question asks about `||` rather than `|`) or side-effects (relevant because the expansion of true, false, XOR and XNOR evaluate their arguments more times than the original constant or operator did).

Comment: The circles containing circles and the transitions form a Hasse Diagram (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram). (Yay, I learned something new today!)

Comment: @DavidRicherby That's true. Other than the XOR, XNOR, true, and false, as far as I can tell, the side effects and number of evaluations should be the same as built-in equivalents (e.g. `!(!A || !B)` has the same short-circuiting and evaluation count as `A && B`). I don't think you can do this for XOR and XNOR without additional constructs (e.g. `a ? !b : b`), and true or false isn't a problem if you can save values, since you could start your program by defining `true` and `false` using some dummy boolean variable.

Comment: It's interesting to note that the list above comprises 16 operations. This is consistent with the fact that there are 16 possible truth tables for the case where you have 2 inputs and 1 output.

Comment: It might be useful to note that you are also using brackets (i.e. precedence), but this is not fundamental, since the same operations can be expressed chronologically (via polish notation).

Comment: Just wanted to add [another visualization as a table](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Logical_connectives_table.svg) for people's reference. Same source as above.

Answer (score 126):

What you are describing is [*functional completeness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness).

This describes a set of logical operators that is sufficient to "express all possible truth tables".  Your Java operator set, {`||`, `!`}, is sufficient; it corresponds to the set {∨, ¬}, which is listed under the section "Minimal functionally complete operator sets".

The set of all truth tables means all possible sets of 4 boolean values that can be the result of an operation between 2 boolean values.  Because there are 2 possible values for a boolean, there are 2<sup>4</sup>, or 16, possible truth tables.

```
A B | 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
----+------------------------------------------------
T T | T  T  T  T  T  T  T  T  F  F  F  F  F  F  F  F
T F | T  T  T  T  F  F  F  F  T  T  T  T  F  F  F  F
F T | T  T  F  F  T  T  F  F  T  T  F  F  T  T  F  F 
F F | T  F  T  F  T  F  T  F  T  F  T  F  T  F  T  F
```

Here is a table of the truth table numbers (0-15), the `||` and `!` combinations that yield it, and a description.

```
Table  |  Operation(s)                    | Description
-------+----------------------------------+-------------
  0    | A || !A                          | TRUE
  1    | A || B                           | OR
  2    | A || !B                          | B IMPLIES A
  3    | A                                | A
  4    | !A || B                          | A IMPLIES B
  5    | B                                | B
  6    | !(!A || !B) || !(A || B)         | XNOR (equals)
  7    | !(!A || !B)                      | AND
  8    | !A || !B                         | NAND
  9    | !(A || !B) || !(!A || B)         | XOR
 10    | !B                               | NOT B
 11    | !(!A || B)                       | NOT A IMPLIES B
 12    | !A                               | NOT A
 13    | !(A || !B)                       | NOT B IMPLIES A
 14    | !(A || B)                        | NOR
 15    | !(A || !A)                       | FALSE
```

There are plenty of other such functionally complete sets, including the one element sets {NAND} and {NOR}, which don't have corresponding single operators in Java.

Comment: +1 for the edit. Despite the difference in vote counts, I think your answer is actually more detailed than mine now.

Comment: Truth Tables i thought i had left them behind after first year in university

Answer (score 80):

Yes.

[All logic gates can be made from NOR gates.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOR_logic)

Since a NOR gate can be made from a NOT and an OR, the result follows.

Comment: @PaulDraper ***or*** NAND gates

Comment: It took 4100 NOR gates to land two people on the moon.

Comment: @HansPassant And some string. Lots of string. (Core rope memory, not the tin can variety.)

Comment: @HansPassant Sometimes I wish Stack Exchange was Wikipedia, then I would insert a `[citation-needed]` mark right there.

Comment: Yes, sorry, [Apollo guidance computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Guidance_Computer#Design).

Comment: to make your answer more complete, it would be nice to show how a NOR gate can be made from a NOT and OR.

Answer (score 64):

Take the time to read up on [DeMorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) if you can.

You will find the answer in the reading there, as well as references to the logical proofs.

But essentially, the answer is yes.

**EDIT**: For explicitness, my point is that one can logically infer an OR expression from an AND expression, and vice-versa. There are more laws as well for logical equivalence and inference, but I think this one most apropos.

---

**EDIT 2**: Here's a proof via truth-table showing the logical equivalence of the following expression.

DeMorgan's Law: `!(!A || !B) -> A && B`

```
 _____________________________________________________
| A | B | !A  | !B  | !A || !B | !(!A || !B) | A && B | 
-------------------------------------------------------
| 0 | 0 |  1  |  1  |    1     |      0      |   0    | 
-------------------------------------------------------
| 0 | 1 |  1  |  0  |    1     |      0      |   0    |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1 | 0 |  0  |  1  |    1     |      0      |   0    |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1 | 1 |  0  |  0  |    0     |      1      |   1    |
_______________________________________________________
```

Comment: Some people have to down vote as part of their "functional completeness"

Comment: At +27/-2, I wouldn't worry much about a stray downvote.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I'm just curious why some people thought my answer was not helpful / was harmful.

Comment: Generally answers that rely on links aren't liked too much (as links die), but in this case any there are so many alternative explanations of DeMorgan's Laws, that I don't see an issue - still, that's my guess as to the DV's

Comment: @user2813274 Thanks for the explanation. Hopefully, my edits will help bridge the gap between personal research and getting to the answer.

Answer (score 11):

[NAND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_gate) and [NOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOR_gate) are universal they can be used to build up any logical operation you want anywhere; other operator are available in programming languages to make it easy to write and make readable codes.

Also all the logical operations which are needed to be hardwired in circuit are also developed using either NAND or NOR only ICs.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, according to Boolean algebra, any Boolean function can be expressed as a sum of minterms or a product of maxterms, which is called *canonical normal form*. There is no reason why such logic couldn't be applied to the same operators used in computer science.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form