# OR operator inside of If statements

Tags: java, if-statement, syntax

```java
else if (!emailGet.endsWith(".com") && !emailGet.endsWith(".info")){ 
    errors += "Email should end with .info or .com";
}
```

Why is `&&` playing the role of an "OR" statement, but when I use "OR" itself it does nothing. The only way I can get the code to tell me if one or the other statement is true, is by using `&&` which evaluates 2 statements unlike "OR", the logic behind using `&&` makes no sense to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: You did not copy all your code!

Comment: `&&` is not at all playing an OR; And what you need is effectivly an `&&` so an AND. With an OR it'll always be true : be because it'll always be different of one option

Comment: The operators for the logical (bitwise) "and" and "or" are `&` and `|`, respectively. Furthermore, the operators `&&` and `||` are shortcut-equivalents: if the left-hand side of an `&&` is `false`, the expression will evaluate to `false` and the right-hand side will not be evaluated; if the left-hand side of an `||` is `true`, the expression will evaluate to `true` and the right-hand side will not be evaluated.

Comment: [How to make logical OR with AND,and NOT?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8374895/15244370) on this same site ((posted code is same as `!(emailGet.endsWith(".com") || emailGet.endsWith(".info")`))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make logical OR with AND,and NOT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374895/how-to-make-logical-or-with-and-and-not)

Answer (score 2):

Note the following concepts about `||` and `&&` operators:

1. When multiple conditions are combined with `&&`, the evaluation of the conditions continues as long as conditions evaluate as `true`. If any condition evaluates as `false`, the further evaluation stops and the combination results in `false`. The combination results in `true` only when all the conditions evaluate as `true`.
2. When multiple conditions are combined with `||`, the evaluation of the conditions continues as long as conditions evaluate as `false`. If any condition evaluates as `true`, the further evaluation stops and the combination results in `true`. The combination results in `false` only when all the conditions evaluate as `false`.

Based on these concepts,

```
!emailGet.endsWith(".com") && !emailGet.endsWith(".info")
```

is same as

```
!(emailGet.endsWith(".com") || emailGet.endsWith(".info"))
```

Let's analyse them in the following scenarios:

#### Let's say emailGet = "a@b.com"

`!emailGet.endsWith(".com") && !emailGet.endsWith(".info")` => `!(true) && !emailGet.endsWith(".info")` => `false && !emailGet.endsWith(".info")` => `false`.

`!(emailGet.endsWith(".com") || emailGet.endsWith(".info"))` => `!(true || emailGet.endsWith(".info"))` => `!(true)` => `false`.

#### Let's say emailGet = "a@b.info"

`!emailGet.endsWith(".com") && !emailGet.endsWith(".info")` => `!(false) && !emailGet.endsWith(".info")` => `true && !(true)` => `true && false` => `false`.

`!(emailGet.endsWith(".com") || emailGet.endsWith(".info"))` => `!(false || true)` => `!(true)` => `false`.

#### Let's say emailGet = "a@b.c"

`!emailGet.endsWith(".com") && !emailGet.endsWith(".info")` => `!(false) && !emailGet.endsWith(".info")` => `true && !(false)` => `true && true` => `true`.

`!(emailGet.endsWith(".com") || emailGet.endsWith(".info"))` => `!(false || false)` => `!(false)` => `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in java the boolean operator for conditional **or** is `||`.(represented by two vertical bars or "pipes", not lowercase L's) Similarly you've already found the boolean operator for conditional **and** which is `&&`. These two are not the same although they will both evaluate to true when both statements are true.

Comment: Isn't the "&&" operator supposed to return something inside the statement  ONLY WHEN both conditions are met "in this case (a missing ".com" and a missing ".info" at the same time)?

Comment: Yes, and theres no way anyone can confirm both of those statements are true without seeing more of your code.

Comment: `||` is **not** the "or"-operator; it is its shortcut-equivalent. The logical (bitwise) "or"-operator is `|`.

Comment: @Turing85 thanks I've made the correction

Comment: Not really. As I said: `|` is the logical (bitwise) "or", `||` is the shortcut-"or".

Comment: Google searches for "logical or" come up with || while "bitwise or" comes up with |. This has been my understanding although I could be mistaken. I've never seen one called logical and (bitwise) at the same time.

Comment: And [the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2) calls them "logical" (`&` and `|`) and "conditional" (`&&` and `||`) operators.

Comment: Guess I was misunderstanding, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the negatives in combination with **and** (`&&`) and **or** (`||`)
caused misunderstanding.

```
    if (!emailGet.endsWith(".com") && !emailGet.endsWith(".info")) {      
        errors += "Email should end with .info or .com";
    }
    if (emailGet.endsWith(".com") || emailGet.endsWith(".info")) {      
        sucesses += "Email did end with .info or .com";
    }
    if (!(emailGet.endsWith(".com") || emailGet.endsWith(".info"))) {      
        errors += "Email should end with .info or .com";
    }
```

It is always:

```
! <this-case> && ! <other-case>
<this-case> || <other-case>
```

Should you see

```
! <this-case> || ! <other-case> // *** ERROR *** always true
<this-case> && <other-case>     // *** ERROR *** always false
```

you know it is wrong.